# How to add Google-Api-Php-Client library in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, integration, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to build an application using Google API. However, I managed to make it to work in `CorePHP`. But I'm not able to integrate the Google API PHP client library in laravel 4.2. Can anybody guide me ?

Comment: What have you already tried ? Are you facing any errors ?

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty confused by integrating the whole library. However, I can add a new class in Laravel but putting that into app/libraries folder but for the whole library. I'm not sure what I need to do. Can u please guide me step by step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Api Client is available via composer. To add it to your Laravel simply run this command in your base Laravel dir

```
composer require google/apiclient
```

Now you can use the google client library in your controller or any other part of laravel

```
$google_client = new Google_Client();
$google_client->setApplicationName('YOUR APPLICATION NAME');
$google_client->setClientId('YOUR CLIENT ID');
$google_client->setClientSecret('SECRET');
```

Comment: thank you Javi.. it worked for me. Sometimes, I was just confused on integrating that library. But found laravel does everything for you itself via composer :)

Comment: hey, but in the client class no name space, how should i add it to my controller?
thanks